# Pandas: average over df rows where a value from another df exists, loops over all rows of second df

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have the following two dataframes `df_1` and `df_2`.

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd

# initialize list of lists
data = [[1, 5, 6.2], 
        [3, 2, 3.2], 
        [4, 5, 9.1],
        [1, 4,8.2],
        [5, 3, 2.4]
        ]

data_id = [[1, 0], 
        [2, 0], 
        [3, 0],
        [4, 0],
        [5, 0]
        ]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['foo', 'baz', "result"])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_id, columns=['zop_id', 'baz'])
```

```
df_1

    foo baz result
0   1   5   6.2
1   3   2   3.2
2   4   5   9.1
3   1   4   8.2
4   5   3   2.4

df_2

    zop_id  baz
0   1   NaN
1   2   NaN
2   3   NaN
3   4   NaN
4   5   NaN
```

The first two columns of `df_1` contain integers numbers ranging `n`, in this case 5.

What I would like to do is fill the second column of `df_2`  by computing the average of the `result` column in `df_1` across all the rows where the relative element of `df_2` is present.

So let us say the second row of `df_2`, the integer value `2` is there. The second column, first row value should be the average of `result` column across all the rows `df_1` where the integer value `2` appears at least one in the first two columns.`2` appears in the second row of the first datafarme and in no other, so the value to fill is the `result` of the second row, `3.2`

I have a truly ugly convoluted solution at the moment

1. getting the value in the first column of the second dataframe
2. iterating over the rows (first two columns) of the first dataframe
3. collect all the values in the third column if the value from 1. is present
4. average

I would like to learn how a proper panda-ista does it, thanks a lot

Comment: error in your code. plz run your example code before asking

Comment: @Panda Kim, corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'foo': [1, 3, 4, 1, 5], 'baz': [5, 2, 5, 4, 3], 'result': [6.2, 3.2, 9.1, 8.2, 2.4]}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

`df_1`

```
    foo baz result
0   1   5   6.2
1   3   2   3.2
2   4   5   9.1
3   1   4   8.2
4   5   3   2.4
```

**Code**

`melt` and `groupby`

```
df_1.melt('result', value_name='zop_id').groupby('zop_id')['result'].mean().reset_index(name='baz')
```

output:

```
   zop_id   baz
0   1       7.20
1   2       3.20
2   3       2.80
3   4       8.65
4   5       5.90
```

**intermediate**

melt df_1

```
df_1.melt('result', value_name='zop_id')
```

output:

```
    result  variable    zop_id
0   6.2     foo         1
1   3.2     foo         3
2   9.1     foo         4
3   8.2     foo         1
4   2.4     foo         5
5   6.2     baz         5
6   3.2     baz         2
7   9.1     baz         5
8   8.2     baz         4
9   2.4     baz         3
```

now we can groupby by zop_id

Comment: I just do not get it why you changed the dataframe definition. Your df_1 is constructed as ````data1 = {'foo': [1, 3, 4, 1, 5], 'baz': [5, 2, 5, 4, 3], 'result': [6.2, 3.2, 9.1, 8.2, 2.4]}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)````, the original (now renamed) as ````df_11```` was built as ````df_11 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['foo', 'baz', " result"])````, why is that ````df_11.equals(df_1) = False````? The ````melt```` method does not work on the original dataframe, they look identical to me though. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user37292 becuz your dataframe have white space in your result column. look ' result' in your code. Someone might try to run the code with this question, but your example was problematic, so I made a new one.

Comment: `df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['foo', 'baz', " result"])` This caused me to get an error when I tried to answer it. It is important to have the habit of checking the examples carefully.

Comment: oh my silly me, thanks again awfully sorry for the mess, shall better correct it